# What is a purely functional data structure for fast nearest neighbor search on n-dimensional space?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming

I'm looking for a purely functional data structure with an API such as:

```
insert  :: Vector n Int -> Struct n -> Struct n
remove  :: Vector n Int -> Struct n -> Struct n
nearest :: Vector n Int -> Struct n -> Vector n Int
```

Or some variation of that, providing fast insertion, removal and query for the nearest element in an n-dimensional space. What is that data-structure?

Comment: Recommending a *data structure* is fundamentally different from recommending a library or external resource. This question is fine and should not be closed.

Comment: A k-d tree works well if the number of dimensions is not to high.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a structure specialized for that operation, quadtrees/k-d trees are more powerful in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a natural generalization of [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) from two dimensions to n.

Answer (score 3):

For an n-dimensional space, there is also the [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).